# Is it possible to hang a bicycle from floating shelf bolts?

Tags: walls

The requirement is to hang a bike on 1" dowel mounted on floating shelf bolts. The bolts will go into studs and their length is 2.5". The bike weighs 60lb and will be 10" away from the wall. I think this isn't going to work; it'll just fall. Anyone have any experience of this?

It's basically this product https://www.amazon.co.uk/ZWEIRAD-Sticks-Copenhagen-various-Natural/dp/B01C34NZAM but a DIY version, with bigger screws.

Comment: Or it will bend the bolts. How thick are the bolts? The further away from the wall the harder it is to hold the weight up without support from a gusset.

Comment: I love how that product comes with hollow wall anchors. :O Your case comes down to the bolt size. Until we have that (exactly, not "bigger"), we have no conversation.

Comment: Are you sure the bike weighs 60 lbs?

Answer (score 1):

To properly analyze this you'd need a good drawing of the forces acting on the system (a free-body diagram). Without seeing that, and without knowing the materials you intend to use (ex. what grade fasteners, what size fasteners, torque values, what type of wood dowels, how the bolts secure the dowels to the stud, etc.) it's incredibly difficult to say whether or not it will work.

My biggest concern is not that the bolts will fail, but that the wood dowel will break in tension. I'd be worried about the area under the fastener head. If you can provide a drawing, I'll try to edit this answer to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

buy two lengths of 1/2" steel rod at the store. drill 1/2"+ (17/32" drill bit) holes 3" in to the center of the edges of the 2x4 studs. slip in the rods. hang your bike. if you want wood over the rods, buy your dowels, drill the out too, possibly using an extension rod for the bit.

Comment: Or go to the auto parts store and purchase some rubber hose that just fits over the steel rods and cut to length and slide in place.

Comment: Or find some 1/2 " or larger rebar and put that into the studs; It should be stronger than cold rolled rod. Or , put the standard hooks into the ceiling.

Comment: Drill the holes with a slight downwards slope so that the bar doesn't fall out.